# How to plot the absolute values of the solutions to a parametric equation versus the parameter?

Tags: plotting, implicit, parameters

**Mathematical formulation of my problem:** Let $\Theta\subset\Bbb R$ be an interval. For each $\theta\in\Theta$ let $f_\theta: \Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ be some function and $z_{\theta,1},\ldots,z_{\theta,n(\theta)}$ the (finitely many) solutions to $f_\theta(z)=0$. I would like to plot the multifunction

$$ \Theta\ni\theta\mapsto \left(|z_{\theta,1}|,\ldots,|z_{\theta,n(\theta)}|\right)\in\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\Bbb R^n$$

in a plot with two axes, one for $\theta$ and one in which all values $|z_{\theta,1}|,\ldots,|z_{\theta,n(\theta)}|$ are plotted.

The specific function I am interested in is essentially

$$ f_\theta(z)=(1+i\theta)z-(1+i)|z|^2z+0.01,$$

so $n(\theta)\le3$. The solutions $z_{\theta,1},\ldots,z_{\theta,n(\theta)}$ need not be exact, numerical approximations will do just fine.

**What I've done so far:** Writing $z=z_1+iz_2$ and using

```
{{z11, z12}, {z21, z22}, {z31, z32}} =
  {z1, z2} /. 
  NSolve[
    z1 - theta z2 - (z1^2 + z2^2) z1 + (z1^2 + z2^2) z2 + 0.01 == 0 &&
    theta z1 + z2 - (z1^2 + z2^2) z1 - (z1^2 + z2^2) z2 == 0,
    {z1, z2}
  ]
```

I get solutions -- plus perhaps some nonsensical solution with "complex real part". So what I could try next is to "forget" these nonsensical solutions and then define a function depending on $\theta$ which I could plot, but I'm kind of lost there since I'm quite new to Mathematica. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand) to construct the appropriate equations for the real and imaginary parts, and then use the domain [`Reals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reals) to make sure that the real and imaginary parts are real numbers. Your function:

```
f[θ_] := (1 + I θ) z - (1 + I) Abs[z]^2 z + 1/100
```

Then, use [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand) to convert to coupled equations for the real and imaginary parts:

```
Thread[
    Block[{z = a + I b}, ComplexExpand[ReIm @ f[θ]]] == 0
]
```

> {1/100 + a - a^3 + a^2 b - a b^2 + b^3 - b θ == 
>     0, -a^3 + b - a^2 b - a b^2 - b^3 + a θ == 0}

Finally, a function to solve the equations:

```
roots[θ_] := With[{eqns = Block[{z = a + I b}, ComplexExpand[ReIm @ f[θ]]]},
     Flatten[{a + b I} /. NSolve[Thread[eqns == 0], {a, b}, Reals]]
]
```

Example:

```
roots[1]
```

> {0.709594 - 0.709594 I, -0.704593 + 0.704593 I, -0.00500025 + 0.00500025 I}

Check:

```
f[1] /. z->roots[1]
```

> {-2.08722*10^-14 + 0. I, 2.88658*10^-15 + 0. I, 2.08619*10^-17 + 0. I}

which is zero up to machine number fuzziness.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice help! Since roots is a multi-valued function where the number of values depends on $\theta$, I still have trouble plotting it. How is it done?